# Unaccept status

Tags: support

I just noticed a negative reputation (by -2) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30131283/jqgrid-not-rendering-data-headers-visible/30133735#30133735)  question. I don't understand; why I have been given a negative score?

It has -1 on the question and not -2. Can I find out who voted in negative?

[image: Screen shot of question rating]

whereas in the summary as you can see it shows -2

[image]

Comment: My guess: Your question looks like a debugging request. You're asking, "Why isn't this working?" instead of "I have [specific error/problem] and have tried X, Y, Z to fix it with no success".

Comment: But I don't get what's wrong in asking that what's wrong with my code if something is not working as I would expect it to. The person who is going to answer can either debug the code that I have provided or can answer from his own past experience. That's where his expertise will come into play.

Comment: *Isn't this contradicting that how can both of those two answers have positive rating when they are about the same thing? One of them should have a negative rating.* Are you asking us to downvote your self-answer?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I was referring to the suggestions (of possible similar questions) that pop-up automatically on my question. How can those two have positive rating when the system itself is suggesting that those two are similar to mine. I hope I did not confuse you any further :)

Comment: *"Can I find out who voted in negative?"* - even if that had been the case: **no**. Voting is anonymous, and looks set to stay that way for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough

Answer (score 6):

You unaccepted an answer on May 9th and then accepted your own. [You do not gain reputation for accepting your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

> If you accept:
>
> - **someone else's answer**: You gain +2 reputation and the author of the accepted answer earns +15 reputation.
> - your own answer: No reputation is awarded, and the answer does not float to the top of the list. You must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer.
> - a community-wiki answer: No reputation is awarded.

Since you had already accepted someone else's answer, that reputation was removed.

---

You can not find out who voted (in any direction). Votes are anonymous. A score of `-1` does not mean 1 reputation point lost. The reputation lose associated with a downvote is not the same as the reputation lose from unaccepting an answer.

Comment: Today's event came after this question was posted. The question was about the unaccept.

Comment: Well what if I either found a better answer or I felt that the answer that I had accepted earlier was not accurate?

Comment: If you found another answer, accepted it, AND it was not your own, you'd have a net 0 reputation change. In your history you'd still see the unaccept, but then you'd also have an accept event.

Comment: My advise: Don't worry about 2 reputation points. You'll earn it back.

Comment: I feel like deleting this question as there are already 5 negative votes. I am just trying to understand the basis. Thanks for your advice though, @Andy. Although I find the website quite useful. It has helped me a lot.

Comment: @raringsunny: Don't worry about rep on meta, there ain't any anyway.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks @Deduplicator

Answer (score 3):

You unaccepted the answer of that question.

When you accept an answer on your question, other than your own answer, you receive two points and the answer poster receives 15 points. If you unaccept that answer, those points go away.

Comment: @Mat Today's event for the question linked came _after_ this Meta post. That was likely a downvote from someone coming from Meta or just coincidentally timed, but is still _after_ the question here was posted.

Comment: Yep, sorry, realized that now.

Comment: People have started voting negative for this post too. All I intended to do is to reach support and find out an answer. I feel that it is incorrect. But what if I was not able to find another similar question.